# How to replace a widget in Qsplitter with another?

Tags: qt, qsplitter

I have one splitter and two widgets... i want to replace the first widget with a splitter, and put in it the first widget and another widget
withe the same arrangement (in runtime)

PS: i can't drop the first widget from the splitter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a new splitter for the replace since QSplitter can handle more than 2 widgets. Say we have two widgets in a splitter:

```
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter(this);
setCentralWidget(splitter);

QTextEdit *widget0 = new QTextEdit;
QTextEdit *widget1 = new QTextEdit;

splitter->addWidget(widget0);
splitter->addWidget(widget1);
```

Now we can put a third widget between these two with:

```
QTextEdit *widget2 = new QTextEdit;
splitter->insertWidget(1, widget2);
```

Now we have the three widgets and two splitters between them in the order of widget0, widget2, widget1.

**Update:**

If the orientation of the second splitter is different, than:

```
QSplitter *splitter2 = new QSplitter;
splitter2->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
QTextEdit *widget2 = new QTextEdit("2");
splitter2->addWidget(widget0);
splitter2->addWidget(widget2);
splitter->insertWidget(0, splitter2);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: actually, the main splitter is horizontally ,and i want to split the first widget into 2 widgets vertically.. i wantd to show it in pictures but i couldn't upload the photo
maybe i didn't explain it clearly in the main question